# Anomalous dimension meaning in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

What is the physical meaning of the anomalous dimension in quantum field theory?

When calculating nonperturbative renormalization group flow equations, I have been using the derivative expansion for the average effective action. So that $\Gamma_k$ is truncated to first-order expansion with a wavefunction renormalization $Z_k$, see https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0005122, page 25.

Later in this paper it states that the anomalous dimension is the partial derivative of $\ln Z_k$ but doesn't say why this needs to be included or what it means?

I have read that a small anomalous dimension means that the theory is well approximated by the classical field theory dimensional analysis, but I don't understand what this means - why do we want this to be the case? Do we want the anomalous dimension to run with the scale like the coupling constants do, or do we want it to be a constant (as I know in the LPA we set $Z_k=1$) so there is no anomalous dimension?